# Jquery HTML Checkbox and PHP iteration not in FOREACH area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**EDIT**
I have a checkbox that iterates 4 times. When the checkbox is clicked, the value is totaled on the sidebar. The sidebar is not in the FOREACH area - it is separate and takes the values stored in the script and displays the totals.

I need to figure out how to grab the Name of the Service and the Individual Price that's within the block of text for each checkbox, but I'm not having any luck doing it. How can I bind the name of the service to the checkbox and display it on the sidebar when the checkbox is checked? Same with the Service Price.

I am using a bind-click code:

```
$('input[id^=ckNow_]').each(function(){
$(this).bind('click',function(){
if($(this).prop('checked'))
{
```

Which ties into:

```
<div id="product_<?php echo $i;?>" name="product_<?php echo $i;?>">
<?php echo $service->PRODUCT; ?>
<input id="hsprice_<?php echo $i;?>" name="hsprice_<?php echo $i;?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo floatval($service->PRICE+$service->TRAVEL);?>">
</input>
<label class="addremove">Add/Remove
<input type="checkbox" class="hideme" id="ckNow_<?php echo $i;?>"  name="ckNow[<?php echo $i;?>]"></input>
</label>
</div>
```

On the right sidebar I'm calling some hidden fields using the check-bind fucntion and that works fine. Now I need to add the Service Name and the individual service price to the sidebar.

How can I do this?

EDIT

I've tried adding to the bind-click event:

```
var service = '#product_'+$(this).attr("id").split("_");
$('#lblServiceName').append($('service').attr('id'));
```

And then called in the sidebar:

```
<p class="alignleft" id="lblServiceName"></p>
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the markup with your checkboxes?  Your question is confusing because you mention checkboxes, but I don't see any in your examples above.  Please clean-up your question, it has way too much information. Provide a simple test case with Markup and what solution you want.  I should be able to help you with this.

Comment: I'd be able to help too but you should consider making your code a little bit "friendlier", better var names and correct indentation would help a lot. Improve your code so we can help you better.